# Getting CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED. How to pass pem file to tinys3 ?

Tags: python, ssl, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload to aws s3. My python program using version 2.7.12

```
import tinys3
S3_ACCESS_KEY=''
S3_SECRET_KEY=''
conn = tinys3.Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY,S3_SECRET_KEY,tls=True)

f = open('D:\\poc\\dicomimage','rb')
conn.upload('D:\\poc\\sampleimage',f,'development/system')
```

But i am getting below error:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

I cannot set tls=False.
I tried below things but getting same error all the time

1. added cert=cert_path, pip.ini
2. Also executed - pip uninstall -y certifi && pip install certifi==2015.04.28, as mentioned in various posts.

How can i pass my pem file to tinys3 or any setting to fix the issue.

PS: I am a full time java developer, fortunately/unfortunately this is my first python program. So, please explain how things are working here.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the endpoint of your bucket

```
conn = tinys3.Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY,S3_SECRET_KEY,tls=True,endpoint='s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com')
```

change your endpoint to match the endpoint of your bucket, check [AWS list of region endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)